# apple pay option not coming in stripe

Tags: python, stripe-payments

backend

```
    @app.route('/create-payment-intent', methods=['POST'])
    def create_payment():
        try:
            data = json.loads(request.data)
            # Create a PaymentIntent with the order amount and currency
            intent = stripe.PaymentIntent.create(
                amount=calculate_order_amount(data['items']),
                currency='usd',
                automatic_payment_methods={
                    'enabled': True,
                },
            )
            return jsonify({
                'clientSecret': intent['client_secret']
            })
        except Exception as e:
            return jsonify(error=str(e)), 403
```

frontend

```
    export default function App() {
    const [clientSecret, setClientSecret] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        // Create PaymentIntent as soon as the page loads
        fetch("/create-payment-intent", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify({ items: [{ id: "xl-tshirt" }] }),
        })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => setClientSecret(data.clientSecret));
    }, []);

    const appearance = {
        theme: "stripe",
    };
    const options = {
        clientSecret,
        appearance,
    };

    return (
        <div className="App">
        {clientSecret && (
            <Elements options={options} stripe={stripePromise}>
            <CheckoutForm />
            </Elements>
        )}
        </div>
    );
    }
```

here is my stripe code where i am expecting google pay to come but it is not coming. I am using live stripe acccount for testing . https://dev.polyverse.app/pay here is the my application you can check.

Answer (score 1):

The Payment Element also supports Google Pay and Apple Pay [0]. There is no need to implement a separate Payment Request button.

Google Pay and Apple Pay are unavailable for merchants and customers in India on Stripe Checkout and Stripe Elements [1] which is probably why you're not seeing these payment method options.

If it helps, I do see Google Pay and Apple Pay as an option to pay with on the URL you've provided.

[0]https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements#apple-pay-and-google-pay

[1]https://support.stripe.com/questions/supported-payment-methods-currencies-and-businesses-for-stripe-accounts-in-india